# Flutter singleton updating a user object doesn't seem to work

Tags: flutter, dart

in my newest app project I wanted to create a singleton for my user object. In this class I want to do all my authentication and relevant todos for my user and I want to get the `currentUser` in my app threw the instance. For what I understand: By making the constructor private, we ensure that the class cannot be instantiated outside the file where it is defined. And as a result, the only way to access it is to call Singleton.instance in the code.

Now this is my auth.dart

```
class Auth {
  /// private constructor
  Auth._();
  /// the one and only instance of this singleton
  static final instance = Auth._();
  
  // Create a User instance. Actually it would be better if this is empty so I can notice if a user is valid or not and can react by checking if the user has values and
  // if not log the user out later on
  User currentUser = User(id: 0, socketId: 'socketId', userName: 'userName');

  updateCurrentUserInstance(User user) async {
    currentUser = user;
    print('updateCurrentUserInstance $currentUser'); // I have the user data I want here! (User(id:1, socketId: 234, userName: updatedUser)
    return currentUser;
  }
}
```

Now with the `updateCurrentUserInstance()` I want to update the `currentUser` object, whenever I have new data for the currently logged in user. In my app I have a place quiet early, where Im getting the credentials (at the moment hardcoded) and call the `updateCurrentUserInstance()` with the new object. If i print the currentUser in the function, I have the currently updated user there. e.g. `(User(id:1, socketId: 234, userName: updatedUser)`

Following the trail in my app we start at the `chat.dart`, where im calling `socketApi.connect()` in `initstate()` before the widget build. In this function im getting the relevant data of the user and update the values in the database, then im calling `auth.updateCurrentUserInstance(user);` where im passing the new user to the above function from `auth.dart`. Like I said before in the print statement we have the `currentUser` with the new values. Now the `initstate` is done. I want to display the value `socketId` of the new user in the `title`, but everything it shows here is the 'socketId' from my currentUser placeholder data.

```
class _ChatState extends State<Chat> {
 
  late SocketApi socketApi;
  DatabaseApi databaseApi = DatabaseApi.db;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
        socketApi = SocketApi(context.read<ChatBloc>());
        socketApi.connect();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
Auth auth = Auth.instance;
   

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
  title: Text("Chatlist of ${auth.currentUser.socketId}"), // <- This should be 234 not 'socketId'
  centerTitle: true,
),
...
```

**I dont understand why this happens.** I called a friend of me who double checked the code, he didn't know about singleton yet, but he said for test purposes try to add a testuser and call the `updateCurrentUserInstance` in the chat.dart

```
final testUser = User(id: 1, socketId: '567', userName: 'User A');
auth.updateCurrentUserInstance(testUser);
```

And yes finally we have 567 as a result in the title. But whats the matter here? I already called the `updateCurrentUserInstance()` outside of `chat.dart` and in the print statement it had the `currentUser` values. Why doesn't it act like a singleton here and why doesn't it provide the updated values of currentUser??

**EDIT**

I also tried to remove the `initstate` and call the function `socketApi.connect();` in the widget tree of `chat.dart` without any difference. In the whole queue until my updated `currentUser` with the correct data there is no issue, but if I print it in the `chat.dart` it isn't there.

Comment: 1 question, how you are able to get context inside initState

Comment: I dont know actually, everything works fine and i dont get any errors and i can access context.read this is from bloc

Comment: I think its because above the chat.dart I have  BlocProvider<ChatBloc>(
      create: (BuildContext context) => ChatBloc(DatabaseApi.db),

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably is you are making some `async` things when you call `socketApi.connect` or maybe something else. It is hard to know since you haven't shared all your code. But since it takes time to run these codes, your `build` method will already be called before running every methods inside the `initState` and so your widget tree will be drawn before it. I believe that is why you are getting the old value, not the new.

A possible solution for this would be:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    initSocketApi();
  }

  Future<void> initSocketApi() async {
    socketApi = SocketApi(context.read<ChatBloc>());
    await socketApi.connect();

    setState(() {});
  }
```

If there is no `async` code running in your project, this would not help. So for further help, you need to share a bit more code to understand the issue clearly.

Note: You should handle these `API-related` things inside your `Bloc`, etc. but not inside widgets if you want to write clean code.

Comment: thank you very much for your assistance. It doesn't solve the problem, would you take the time and checkout the rest of my code? I would add the other files in my question then

Comment: I can try to help, and maybe it would be nice to see the `socketApi` if you can share it.

Comment: There you go https://github.com/yaitmou/flutter_socket_bloc/blob/main/lib

Comment: as far as i can see, my auth class is correct, the problem is somewhere else... i have a local version of the code where i experimented and put the connection out of chat in the home file and changed some code and refactored every stateful to stateless widget, this seems to fix it in some way, but im actually just trying out without knowing the real issue, so maybe you can detect something else in the socket api file? The database api looks fine for me since everything done there is working

Comment: "You should handle these API-related things inside your Bloc, etc. but not inside widgets if you want to write clean code." im not so familiar yet with bloc, do i need a new bloc for database and for the socket then? how would they look like?